# Specify the instance of a PerWebRequest component at runtime in castle windsor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, castle-windsor, castle, windsor-3.0

I currently work in a asp.net MVC Web Api project using castle 3.1.

I registered a component with a lifestyle 'PerWebRequest'.

I would like to manually tell castle which instance to use instead of letting the container create the instance. On each web request.

Here's how I achieve this:

I cache the HttpRequestMessage instance in the HttpContext's Items collection via a DelegatingHandler(for those who don't know, DelegatingHandler are first extension point offered by the WebApi framework).
When registering my component, I use a factory and retrieve the HttpRequestMessage from the context.

Here's the code:

```
public class InjectingCurrentHttpRequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.AddHttpRequest(request);

        var output = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        HttpContext.Current.RemoveHttpRequest();

        return output;

    }
}
```

Here's how I register my component:

```
container.Register(Component.For<HttpRequestMessage>()
                            .LifestylePerWebRequest()
                            .UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
                            {
                                var context = HttpContext.Current;
                                if (context == null)
                                    throw new Exception("HttpContext is null. Resolving HttpRequestMessage can only be done during an http request. Have you forgot to add the '" + typeof(InjectingCurrentHttpRequestHandler).Name + "' handler in the framework?");

                                return context.GetHttpRequest();
                            }));
```

It does work but I would like to avoid using the HttpContext.Current instance. Is there a better way to achieve this using castle?

I feel like the support for this should be built-in castle, but can't find it.

Thank you,

Comment: I'm confused... why you are registering in the container a class such HttpRequestMessage which is a "data" class? What are you trying to accompish here? It seems you are using the container to "park" an instance...

Comment: Good question, the mvc web api framework uses the HttpRequestMessage to create response message. For example: request.CreateErrorResponse(statusCode, error). So even if the HttpRequestMessage is only a data class at its root, there is logic associated to it via extension methods. I need this instance to create an error response message in one of my class.

Comment: Where are you using such class that create the error response? Usually I have a class like that as dependency of my message handler which has a method the accept in input the request instead of using the container to "share" the request

Comment: I am using an IFilterProvider. IFilterProvider are instanciated once during the initialization of the application. So by design, they do not have access to the current request.
In my case, the IFilterProvider might throw an exception in some specific case. Letting this exception bubble up will end up in a mvc default response message format. This is not acceptable for us as it breaks our api (different json schema for errors). So, long story short, in a custom IFilterProvider, I need to handle my exception to return it in the proper json format to the client.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm lost... IFilterProvider(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.ifilterprovider.getfilters(v=vs.108).aspx) should be responsable only to supply a list of filter according to global registration or class/action attribute. If you replace default one w/ your own implmentation you need to implement GetFilters which give you access to the request...

Comment: The whole point of this is because the IFilterProvider does NOT provide the parameters to access the current request. Unfortunately, in one of my custom IFilterProvider, I need to access the current HttpRequestMessage.

If you can access the current request from within the IFilterProvider.GetFilters parameters, please show me how.

Comment: Good question indeed. I've been confused by mvc version, that has ControllerContext as input parameter... which is missing within webapi version. I'll try to investigate it... LMK if you find anything.

Comment: Hi Jean-Francois, did you find a solution? I'm facing with same problem :(

Comment: @doganak, unfortunately not. I use the code displayed in the current post. Works fine in WebAPI. If you find a better solution, please post it here. :)